# Rescaling image texture in node editor

Tags: texturing, node-editor, export

Is it possible to rescale image textures inside the node editor? 
For example lets say I load in Base Color at 4k. Is it possible to use nodes to turn this image texture to 512 with nodes? 
(Just noticing when playing around with .glb's that the textures tend to make the files pretty big so it'd be nice to be able to downscale the textures for final export while working with bigger textures.)

Thanks

Comment: How are you exporting the model? Are you rendering it in Blender? Isn't it important to preview the resolution you are exporing when working with the model, thus shouldn't you use the 512 res in Blender to begin with?

Comment: Use your favorite image editing app to make a smaller resolution file at 512pixels, use that to work on blender. To render then just replace that file in the texture for the large one. A good rule of thumb is that textures should not be any larger than the size they will occupy on the screen in the final render. Having a very large texture on an object that will be small on the screen is just a waste of resources.

Comment: Of course it is important to preview your final res but that final res isn't always single resolution carved in stone. (For example LODs)
In this case specifically I noticed when I wanted to export a model with 4k textures that the final .glb (glTF binary file) just becomes way too big for uploading to sites. So rather than having to rescale all my image textures manually for all different cases it'd be lot easier to have max res and be able to downscale that inside node editor if need be.

Comment: I actually noticed this is sort of "possible" in Blender. When you go to simplify tab you can set the max size for viewport and rendered view textures. However, as this doesn't really affect exports that pack textures it doesn't really help me. Well anyhow I suppose if there was solution for that currently someone would have pointed it out by now so guess it just isn't something that has been implemented.